# jQuery JSON.parse exception

Tags: javascript, jquery

This will fail:

```
 var obj= JSON.parse('{"a": "\"aa\" vv","b": "b"}');
```

-> *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 8*
Whats the issue here? White space beteween a and v?
documentations say that this should be working fine?

thx

Comment: Try it and play with it here: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Escape the backslash : `var obj= JSON.parse('{"a":"\\"aa\\" vv","b":"b"}');`

Comment: Please see my answer for explaination of, why single escaping is not working here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `\\` instead of `\`

```js
var obj= JSON.parse('{"a": "\\"aa\\" vv","b": "b"}');
console.log(obj.a);
console.log(obj.b);
```

Comment: arrgh. JSONeditor generated this text. It obviously uses different escaping. shouldn't this be the same as jQuery itself?

Answer (score 0):

You should use double back slash `\\` :

```
var obj= JSON.parse('{"a": "\\"aa\\" vv","b": "b"}');
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is explaination of difference between `\` and `\\` usage between simpleObject and object in form of String as argument of `JSON.parse()`

```js
var realObj= {"a": "\"aa\" vv","b": "b"};  // doubleQuote is escaped with single \ so that doubleQuote becomes part of value string in key-value pair. Hence, single backwardSlash
console.log("realObj.a==>"+realObj.a);
console.log("realObj.b==>"+realObj.b);

var objFromParsedJSON= JSON.parse('{"a": "\\"aa\\" vv","b": "b"}'); //doubleQuote is escaped with double \\ so that the argument of JSON.parse should also escape doubleQuote and interpret it as \" after processing. Hence, double \\
console.log("objFromParsedJSON.a==>"+objFromParsedJSON.a);
console.log("objFromParsedJSON.b==>"+objFromParsedJSON.b);
```